# Who did Benjamin think Thon Thaddeo was?

Tags: a-canticle-for-leibowitz

In Miller's *A Canticle for Leibowitz*, at the end of the *Fiat Lux* section, Benjamin, the seemingly immortal Jewish hermit, interrupts Thon Thaddeo's farewell dinner.

As I recall, he (Benjamin) gets very excited, grabs Thon Thaddeo's arm, and looks searchingly at him.  However, this quickly turns to disappointment, and he turns to the assembled monks and says something to the effect of "It's not him" or "he is not the one".

> He came close to the lectern, paused. His eyes twitched over the startled speaker. His mouth quivered. He smiled. He reached out one trembling hand toward the scholar. The thon drew back with a snort of revulsion.
>
> The hermit was agile. He vaulted to the dais, dodged the lectern, and seized the scholar's arm.
>
> "What madness-"
>
> Benjamin kneaded the arm while he stared hopefully into the scholar's eyes.
>
> His face clouded. The glow died. He dropped the arm. A great keening sigh came from the dry old lungs as hope vanished. The eternally knowing smirk of the Old Jew of the Mountain returned to his face. He turned to the community, spread his hands, shrugged eloquently.
>
> "It's still not Him," he told them sourly, then hobbled away.

Who was he looking for, and why did he think Thon Thaddeo may have been him?  Why did he decide Thon Thaddeo wasn't, after all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the explanations for Bejamin's character is that he is the [Wandering Jew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandering_Jew), and is forced to live until the Second Coming.

So, if he is the Wandering Jew, then he's most likely under the impression that Thon Thaddeo is the Second Coming, and after so long on Earth (Per Wikipedia,'Fiat Lux' takes place in 3174) he might just be checking anyone held in high regard. It's also been a long while since I read it, and don't have the book with me to review that scene, but since it happened at Thon's farewell dinner, Benjamin might have gotten some serous Last Supper vibes off the scene and that could have contributed.

As for why he decided Thon wasn't 'The One'? Well, if Thon really WAS Christ, Benjamin's punishment would be over and he'd be wandering the Earth no longer. He's still around to wander the Earth, so Thon must not have been Christ.

Answer (score 4):

Benjamin's dialogue here and elsewhere gives a few clues about whom he might be expecting. In Chapter 16 (in the section *Fiat Lux*), Abbot Paulo rides out to meet Benjamin, whom he regards as a friend. Benjamin hasn't seen Paulo in several years. He watches Paulo approach from a distance, not yet close enough to recognize him.

> He watched the dust speck until it passed through the 
>   village of Sanly Bowitts and departed again by way of the 
>   road leading past the mesa.
>
> "Ah!" snorted the hermit, his eyes beginning to burn. "*His* 
>   empire shall be multiplied, and there shall be no end of *his* 
>   peace: *he* shall sit upon *his* kingdom."

This is an extract from the Book of the Prophet Isaiah (or Isaias), as it appears in the Douay-Rheims-Challoner Bible, the standard English bible used by the Catholic Church until the Second Vatican Council in the 1960s. The full extract, Isaias 9:6–7, reads:

> For a CHILD IS BORN to us, and a son is given to us, and the government is upon his shoulder: and his name shall be called, Wonderful, Counsellor, God the Mighty, the Father of the world to come, the Prince of Peace. His empire shall be multiplied, and there shall be no end of peace: he shall sit upon the throne of David, and upon his kingdom; to establish it and strengthen it with judgment and with justice, from henceforth and for ever: the zeal of the Lord of hosts will perform this.

The Catholic Church regards this as a prophecy of the birth of Jesus Christ.

When Paulo gets close enough that Benjamin can recognize him, Benjamin quotes more scripture from the same passage, then complains:

> His eyes blazed for a moment. "For a Child is born to us, and a Son is given us . . ." But then the anxious frown melted away into sadness. "It's not Him!" he grumbled irritably at the sky.

There is only one Being whose name and referents are routinely capitalized by the Catholic Church: God. The same capitalization, of course, is used to refer to Jesus as well.

As the two are conversing later in the chapter, Benjamin makes comments leading Paulo to believe that a new Renaissance is coming. Paulo seems to want advice from Benjamin, who is not very forthcoming:

> [Paulo:] "If you wait to examine the entrails of 
>   an era until after it's born, it's too late to prophesy its 
>   birth."
>
> "Nonsense. Probing the womb of the future is bad for the 
>   child. I shall wait—and then I shall prophesy that it *was* 
>   born and that it *wasn't* what I'm waiting for."
>
> "What a cheerful outlook! So what *are* you looking for?"
>
> "Someone who shouted at me once."
>
> "Shouted?"
>
> "'Come forth!'"
>
> "What rot!"
>
> "*Hmmm-hnnn*! To tell you the truth, I don't much expect 
>   Him to come, but I was told to wait, and—" he shrugged "—
>   I wait."

This seems to be a reference both to the Biblical story of the raising of Lazarus in [the Gospel of John, chapter 11 verses 1–44](http://www.usccb.org/bible/john/11), and to the [legend of the Wandering Jew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandering_Jew). I'm unable to find any instances of the two characters being identified with each other outside this book, but that clearly appears to be the intention.

The excerpt you cite has the same capitalization of the word "Him". On that basis, **it appears that Benjamin believed that Thon Taddeo might have been Jesus, or at any rate a Messiah.**

Why did he believe this? He's looking for a change in the world, as evident in the dialogue fragment above; and like many Jews of the first century, he believed that God would send a Messiah who would change the world and restore Israel.

Finally, why did he decide the Thon was not? It's apparent that he has a rather pessimistic outlook on life, for one thing. In addition, the Thon is "revolted" by his approach, which was probably not expected behavior for a messiah. Finally, perhaps Benjamin can see at a glance what took Dom Paulo a while to get from the Thon's own mouth:

> "I can see the misunderstanding is basic!" the abbot said 
>   gruffly. "To serve God first, or to serve Hannegan first—that's your choice."
>
> "I have little choice, then," answered the thon. "Would you 
>   have me work for the Church?" The scorn in his voice was 
>   unmistakable.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Benjamin, the Wandering Jew was actually Lazarus, whom Jesus raised from the dead.   Whether Lazarus or not, I recall the book implied that he had met Jesus face to face, so would be able to recognise that Thon was not the same person.